# Mapping data points to a circle

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I have some $d$-dimensional data points ($d \ge 2$). I want map them to a circle such that locality is preserved as much as possible.

I know that PCA only maps points to a line ($d'=1$) or a plane ($d'=2$), but I want them on a circle.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of the data and especially the intention of the mapping (a visualization)? Will the resulting map onto the circle be 1d or 2d in polar coordinates? And related, why isn't utilizing a 1d or 2d PCA projection and just using polar coordinates sufficient (do you have circular data to begin with)?

Comment: "As much as possible" needs to be quantified. For instance, consider the $d=2$ point set $\{(\cos(2\pi j/n),\sin(2\pi j/n), j=1,\ldots,n\}\cup\{(0,M),(M,M),(M,0)\}$ for very large integral $n$ and large $M$. Minimizing the maximum error would cause us to map all the first $n$ points to one vertex of a square and each of the remaining three points to its other vertices, but minimizing (say) the RMS error for $n\gg M$ would keep the the first $n$ points fixed and map the remaining three points somewhere near that circle: a completely different solution.

Comment: My intention is to index the data points. In fact, I want to solve a problem similar to TSP, and want to minimize the total length of the points on the circle (including the distance between the last and the first point). If my data points was in 2D, I could use space filling curves such as Moore or  sierpiński curves, but I want such an indexing for d>2. Dear whuber, I need a mapping where different data points are mapped to different points on a circle and minimize the total length of points on the circle.

Comment: Space filling curves don't "preserve locality" at all! Points that originally are very close will wind up very far from each other. Also, to "minimize the total length" on a circle, just make the circle infinitesimally small :-). All facetiousness aside, you need to clarify your objectives if this question is to be answerable.